# What is the difference between a static const and constexpr variable?

Tags: c++, c++11, static-variables, constexpr

I understand that a `constexpr` **variable** can be used at compiletime.
For a template, or static asser for instance.

But if I want to do that without constexpr I can with `static const`.

What is since C++11/14 introduced constexpr the difference between

```
constexpr int a = 3;
//AND
static const int a = 3;
```

Thank you!

Another way to see this question is **which should I use?**

Comment: It very much depends on *where* you have the declaration. The `static` qualifier does different things in different places.

Comment: `constexpr` also works for non-`int`s.

Comment: @KerrekSB for what is worth, so does `const`.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: `struct Foo { static const double x = 1.5; };`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The main difference that I know is, the value of `constexpr` must be known in compile-time while a `const static` can be assigned in run-time.

```
const static int x = rand();
```

Comment: Ok, so for the use I wrote there would be no difference, this is just for dynamically initialized variable (like first time you evaluate the scope of a function)?